# Get a static final field in scala with a string reference

Tags: scala, reflection

Suppose I have a fully qualified reference string:

```
val location = "org.path.to.some.field"
val foo = getFieldFromString(location)
```

I want to get the same value as if I did:

```
import org.path.to.some.field
```

How do I do this? Does it make sense to use reflection?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be the way to do it:

```
Class.forName("org.path.to.some").getField("field").get(null)
```

One problem is that you do need to know the type of the field in order for this to return something other than AnyRef. The `get(null)` is because we don't need an instance to get the static field.